# Friedman test to report on occurrence of categories in multiple articles

Tags: repeated-measures, ranking

To investigate reasons for certain behavior, we have defined three categories for these reasons, and have determined how often these were mentioned across 15 (very different) scientific articles. These articles were selected by systematic review of titles and abstracts. They span the whole (broad) medical field and are very heterogeneous in methodology and setting.

I want to report on which category of reasons is the most 'important' category for the investigated behavior. **I.e. if one category is mentioned significantly more often than the others.**

Our data is as follows, we have a table with the 15 articles for rows, and the categories as columns. Each cell shows how often an article has mentioned a category in absolute numbers. Like so:

```
Art C1  C2  C3
1   10  3   2
2    7  18  1
3    5  2   7
etc...
```

After much consideration my idea would be to use the Friedman test to determine if one category is mentioned significantly more often than the others, or to show the mean rank of one category is significantly higher than the others. First question, assuming the data, would this be the right test?

Second question, should I use the actual occurrences in the articles as data in the table? EG:

```
Art C1  C2  C3
1   10  3   2
2    7  18  1
3    5  2   7
etc...
```

Or ranked?

```
Art C1 C2  C3
1    3  2   1
2    2  3   1
3    2  1   3
```

And then I would report the mean rank and the result of the Friedman test e.g. the probability that the difference in mean rank is based on chance"

So two questions:

1. Friedman, good idea?
2. List the data with the absolute numbers,
   or ranked?

Comment: The Kruskal Wallis test might be good.

Comment: I considered it, but as these are "repeated measures" I thought I ahd to use Friedman?

Comment: I personally dislike the bounty system. It's better to consider why a question didn't attract (enough) interest and to revise it to add more information. Here there could be several reasons why you got very little attention.

Comment: 1. Most "important". You don't explain your idea of importance, but this seems to call for descriptive statistics, not testing.

Comment: 2. Repeated measures. Your data don't sound like repeated measures in the strict sense. Even if they were I fail to see why that makes Friedman more advisable than Kruskal-Wallis. Neither is aimed at repeated measures.

Comment: 3. Actual occurrences or ranks to be fed to a test. Whenever a test uses ranks any way, it makes no difference whether you rank first or get the test function (command, routine).

Comment: 4. Your example isn't clear. Why does article #1 appear twice? Are figures adjusted for length of articles, i.e. counting mentions should be scaled by length, it might be thought.

Comment: 5. Significance tests don't produce the probability that observed results are due to chance. That's a misinterpretation of significance levels, even if one that is common.

Comment: 6. Perhaps most important for you, what precisely is the scientific hypothesis you think you are testing here? How does the Friedman test relate to that?

Comment: Sorry if my way of commenting seems awkward or perverse, but my attitude to bounties means that I don't want to play that game. I suggest that you use these comments to revise your question so that it makes more sense. The expertise on CV is not really the issue; trying to disentangle what looks like a rather tangled question is more to the point.

Comment: 3 (revised). ... or get the test function (command, routine) to do that for you.

Comment: Uhm ok.. Thanks I guess? If my question wasnt clear, why did nobody say so? I just go zero response, hence the bounty

Comment: 2. What do you mean neither is aimed at repeated measures? "The Friedman test is used for one-way *repeated measures* analysis of variance by ranks."

Comment: 3. Ok that makes sense of course. 4. Typo, should be a '3' 6. I am trying to determine which category is used most often, and the hypothesis would be that The mean rank of categorie X is not based on chance but due to actually appearing more often.

Comment: Standard stuff: see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_measures_design and note the emphasis on longitudinal study. (I can't respond to an unsourced quotation.) Having different categories is not I think sufficient for most statistical people to start talking about repeated measures.

Comment: The quote about Friedman: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test, I'm not very sure about my data being repeated measures, although if you compare it to the classic wine tasting example it's very similar. But I'm pretty sure Friedmans test was designed for repeated measures, as apparently the interwebs agree with me.

Comment: I've suggested that you revise your question. My use of comments is driven by my personal bias against bounties. Piecemeal replies to my comments will not make your question much easier to understand by others, which should now be your main goal. I'm not volunteering to stick with you in indefinite dialogue. The main problem here as I see it is that your question seemed confused and unclear, which is why people did not respond in detail.

Comment: I've revised 2 small things. But I don't understand what's unclear about the question. I want to determine which of the mentioned categories in the articles is mentioned most often. Is that unclear?

Comment: What's unclear is why you think that has anything to with a test. It's just descriptive statistics.

Comment: Well, because I want to show that one category is actually mentioned more often instead of saying it appears that way. Why should that not be testable, assuming the data I have.

Comment: That was not your wording; again, you need to revise your question. There will always be a most popular category, setting aside the possibility of tied frequencies. The uncertainty associated with each frequency of mentions depends on your sampling design, e.g. how you chose 15 articles? I doubt very much that you can translate that into anything standard statistically.

Comment: I tried to improve the question, what do you think? Better? If I cant use any test that would be an answer as well of course :).

Comment: I will give this one more shot. I don't see that the Friedman test has any real bearing on your interest in the most common category. Expectations for the frequency of the most common category must come from a model (generating process) for the data, and I see no model here, unless it is implicitly equal importance of categories. But look at Wilkinson, Leland. 2006. Revising the Pareto chart.  American Statistician 60(4): 332-334 for an indirect approach. You could bootstrap the sample proportions. What kind of sample you have seems a serious issue.